# C++ template function compiles in header but not implementation

Tags: c++, templates, stl, vector, g++

I'm trying to learn templates and I've run into this confounding error.  I'm declaring some functions in a header file and I want to make a separate implementation file where the functions will be defined.

Here's the code that calls the header (`dum.cpp`):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "dumper2.h"

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v;
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        v.push_back(i);
    }
    test();
    std::string s = ", ";
    dumpVector(v,s);
}
```

Now, here's a working header file (`dumper2.h`):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

void test();

template <class T> void dumpVector(const std::vector<T>& v,std::string sep);

template <class T> void dumpVector(const std::vector<T>& v, std::string sep) {
    typename std::vector<T>::iterator vi;

    vi = v.cbegin();
    std::cout << *vi;
    vi++;
    for (;vi<v.cend();vi++) {
        std::cout << sep << *vi ;
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
    return;
}
```

With implementation (`dumper2.cpp`):

```
#include <iostream>
#include "dumper2.h"

void test() {
    std::cout << "!olleh dlrow\n";
}
```

The weird thing is that if I move the code that defines `dumpVector` from the `.h` to the `.cpp` file, I get the following error:

```
g++ -c dumper2.cpp -Wall -Wno-deprecated
g++ dum.cpp -o dum dumper2.o -Wall -Wno-deprecated
/tmp/ccKD2e3G.o: In function `main':
dum.cpp:(.text+0xce): undefined reference to `void dumpVector<int>(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [dum] Error 1
```

So why does it work one way and not the other?  Clearly the compiler can find `test()`, so why can't it find `dumpVector`?

Comment: hehe, i reversed hello and world but put them in the wrong order!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The problem you're having is that the compiler doesn't know which versions of your template to instantiate.  When you move the implementation of your function to x.cpp it is in a different translation unit from main.cpp, and main.cpp can't link to a particular instantiation because it doesn't exist in that context.  This is a well-known issue with C++ templates.  There are a few solutions:

1) Just put the definitions directly in the .h file, as you were doing before.  This has pros & cons, including solving the problem (pro), possibly making the code less readable & on some compilers harder to debug (con) and maybe increasing code bloat (con).

2) Put the implementation in x.cpp, and `#include "x.cpp"` from within `x.h`.  If this seems funky and wrong, just keep in mind that `#include` does nothing more than read the specified file and compile it *as if that file were part of `x.cpp`*  In other words, this does exactly what solution #1 does above, but it keeps them in seperate physical files.  When doing this kind of thing, it is critical that you not try to compile the `#include`d file on it's own.  For this reason, I usually give these kinds of files an `hpp` extension to distinguish them from `h` files and from `cpp` files.

### File: dumper2.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

void test();
template <class T> void dumpVector( std::vector<T> v,std::string sep);
#include "dumper2.hpp"
```

### File: dumper2.hpp

```
template <class T> void dumpVector(std::vector<T> v, std::string sep) {
  typename std::vector<T>::iterator vi;

  vi = v.begin();
  std::cout << *vi;
  vi++;
  for (;vi<v.end();vi++) {
    std::cout << sep << *vi ;
  }
  std::cout << "\n";
  return;

}
```

3) Since the problem is that a particular instantiation of `dumpVector` is not known to the translation unit that is trying to use it, you can force a specific instantiation of it in the same translation unit as where the template is defined.  Simply by adding this:  `template void dumpVector<int>(std::vector<int> v, std::string sep);` ... to the file where the template is defined.  Doing this, you no longer have to `#include` the `hpp` file from within the `h` file:

### File: dumper2.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

void test();
template <class T> void dumpVector( std::vector<T> v,std::string sep);
```

### File: dumper2.cpp

```
template <class T> void dumpVector(std::vector<T> v, std::string sep) {
  typename std::vector<T>::iterator vi;

  vi = v.begin();
  std::cout << *vi;
  vi++;
  for (;vi<v.end();vi++) {
    std::cout << sep << *vi ;
  }
  std::cout << "\n";
  return;
}

template void dumpVector<int>(std::vector<int> v, std::string sep);
```

By the way, and as a total aside, your template function is taking a `vector` *by-value*.  You may not want to do this, and pass it by reference or pointer or, better yet, pass iterators instead to avoid making a temporary & copying the whole vector.

Comment: +1: dumper2.hpp is now a translation unit unto itself. So I would call it dumper2.cpp instead.

Comment: thanks for this thorough response.  I've gone for your 3rd suggestion.

Re your aside, I usually pass vectors as const references (omitted for brevity in the sample code).  Is it better to pass iterators?

Comment: @flies:  "Better" is a matter of subjective opinion.  In my subjective opinion, passing iterators is better because it is more STL-ish (meaning it works better with the STL) and somewhat easier to extend & change.

Comment: Aren't dumper.h and .cpp in the same translation unit since .cpp includes .h?  if so, then I don't understand why there's a problem, and if not then I don't understand translation units (which I had never heard of before asking this question but looked it up in Stroustrup).

Comment: @flies:  which solution are you referring to?

Comment: i was referring to the initial problem.

wait - i think i've got it now, the problem is that main.cpp includes dumper.h, not dumper.cpp, so the implementation for dumper.cpp is in a diff't translation unit than main.cpp.  

That being the case, it's not clear to me why solution 3 works.

Comment: solution 3 only works if you include the template void dumpVector<int>(std::vector<int> v, std::string sep); line for each type you wish to send to the function. this is completely contrary to the point of using templates. Why is c++ this confusing? [Previous version of this comment, dating to 2010, used language I'm not proud of.]

Answer (score 12):

This was what the `export` keyword was supposed to accomplish (i.e., by `export`ing the template, you'd be able to put it in a source file instead of a header. Unfortunately, only one compiler (Comeau) ever really implemented `export` completely.

As to why the other compilers (including gcc) didn't implement it, the reason is pretty simple: because `export` is extremely difficult to implement correctly. Code *inside* the template can change meaning (almost) completely, based on the type over which the template is instantiated, so you can't generate a conventional object file of the result of compiling the template. Just for example, `x+y` might compile to native code like `mov eax, x/add eax, y` when instantiated over an `int`, but compile to a function call if instantiated over something like `std::string` that overloads `operator+`.

To support separate compilation of templates, you have to do what's called two-phase name lookup (i.e., lookup the name both in the context of the template *and* in the context where the template is being instantiated). You typically also have the compiler compile the template to some sort of database format that can hold instantiations of the template over an arbitrary collection of types. You then add in a stage between compiling and linking (though it can be built into the linker, if desired) that checks the database and if it doesn't contain code for the template instantiated over all the necessary types, re-invokes the compiler to instantiate it over the necessary types.

Due to the extreme effort, lack of implementation, etc., the committee has voted to remove `export` from the next version of the C++ standard. Two other, rather different, proposals (modules and concepts) have been made that would each provide at least part of what `export` was intended to do, but in ways that are (at least hoped to be) more useful and reasonable to implement.

Answer (score 7):

Template parameters are resolved as compile time.

The compiler finds the .h, finds a matching definition for dumpVector, and stores it. The compiling is finished for this .h. Then, it continues parsing files and compiling files. When it reads the dumpVector implementation in the .cpp, it's compiling a totally different unit. Nothing is trying to instantiate the template in dumper2.cpp, so the template code is simply skipped. The compiler won't try every possible type for the template, hoping there will be something useful later for the linker.

Then, at link time, no implementation of dumpVector for the type int has been compiled, so the linker won't find any. Hence why you're seeing this error.

The [export](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.14) keyword is designed to solve this problem, unfortunately few compilers support it. So keep your implementation with the same file as your definition.

Answer (score 2):

A template function is not real function.  The compiler turns a template function into a real function when it encounters a use of that function.  So the entire template declaration has to be in scope it finds the call to `DumpVector`, otherwise it can't generate the real function.
Amazingly, a lot of C++ intro books get this wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly how templates work in C++, you must put the implementation in the header.

When you declare/define a template function, the compiler can't magically know which specific types you may wish to use the template with, so it can't generate code to put into a .o file like it could with a normal function. Instead, it relies on generating a specific instantiation for a type when it sees the use of that instantiation.

So when the implementation is in the .C file, the compiler basically says "hey, there are no users of this template, don't generate any code". When the template is in the header, the compiler is able to see the use in main and actually generate the appropriate template code.

Answer (score 0):

Most compilers don't allow you to put template function definitions in a separate source file, even though this is technically allowed by the standard.

See also:

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.12

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.14

Comment: these links are the most complete answer to the question i've found.

Comment: I believe the claim that "Most compilers don't allow you to put template function definitions in a separate source file" is not completely accurate.  See my post in this thread.