# Explicit template instantiation through a typedef

Tags: c++, templates

If I have

```
typedef Foo<float> Foof;
```

why can't I explicitly instantiate the template like this

```
template class Foof;
```

and is there a workaround apart from typing `Foo<float>`?

Comment: @Kay: I would like to explicitly instantiate `Foof` template class for `float` so that I don't get linking errors (and without including the template definitions)

Comment: Thanks for the -1 without explaining why :)

Comment: instantiation is not what you wrote in the second code that is definition¿???? what would you like to do?

Comment: @Gabriel: That is NOT a definition, please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3534789/368599

Comment: @Samaursa thanks! Did not had that quite in mind! Actually I had to explicitly instantiate function templates (cuda kernels wrappers in C++) too, when I was working with CUDA,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> and is there a workaround apart from typing Foo?

No, unfortunately there isn't. You have to type `Foo<float>`. As to why, see 14.7.2 clause 3 of the C++ standard for the rule (I don't know the rationale behind the rule though).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use a macro to define a macro in the header with the full definition of `Foof` and then use that for both the typedef and the explicit-instantiation. That would leak macros from your header and force your header to contain the *exploded* definition of `Foof` (which may be a mess of type-aliases). You only need to write out `Foof` once though.

If what you really want to do is keep your instantiation *synchronized with the definition*, then I can recommend the following:

foo2.h:

```cpp
template<typename T>
using Foo = Bar<int,int,T,T>; // Foo is actually something messy.

typedef Foo<float> Foof; // "Primary" typedef in header uses Foo.
```

foo2.c:

```cpp
#include "foo.h"
#define FOOF_DEF Bar<int,int,float,float> // Requires fully-exploded type.
template class FOOF_DEF; // Explicitly instantiate the class.
typedef FOOF_DEF Foof; // Compiler will error if Foof defs not same.
```

This *does* require you to write-out the definition twice, but the `typedef` in **foo.c** will cause compiler-errors if the types become desynchronized, and the message will likely contain the exploded type-definition you need for updating `FOOF_DEF` to match the header.

Comment: Meh. I would rather do `using FoofElemType = float; using Foof = Foo<FoofElemType>;`.