# Pass derived object to function and access overridden member function

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I‘m trying to pass a pointer to an object which class inherits from another class to a function and then access the member functions of it.

This is the base class:

```cpp
class Base
{
public:
  virtual int funcA(int paramA) = 0;
}
```

This is the derived class:

```cpp
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
  Derived();
  ~Derived();
  int funcA(int paramA);
}

Derived::Derived() {}
Derived::~Derived() {}
Derived::funcA(int paramA)
{
  // SOMETHING
}
```

And the function should look something like this:

```cpp
template<class T> // T should only be types that are derived from Base
void funcB(T* object)
{
  object.funcA(10);
}
```

I‘ve already tried many different things but none of them compiled because I‘m trying to access a function of a template.

Comment: "_I‘ve already tried many different things but none of them worked_" Please define what you mean by "none of them worked".

Comment: None of those things compiled because I was trying to acces a specific function of a template

Comment: Use `std::enable_if`

Comment: It's `object->funcA(10)`, as you have a pointer.  You wrote a dot, which will not compile.  The base/derived issues have nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the definition of `Derived::funcA(int paramA)` lacks the return argument `int` and having a return type `int` it will have to return something e.g. `paramA`. For the sake of clarity that you want to override the function of the `Base` class I would also mark `funcA` as `override` or `final`.
Secondly by passing a pointer to `funcB` you will have to access the member function with the **arrow operator `->`** instead of the dot operator `.`. The cleanest way of implementing this would be to activate the function with `SFINAE` (`std::enable_id`) only if the template argument `T` inherits from `Base`. For C++17 this would look like

```
template<class T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<Base, T>, void>
funcB(T* object) {
  object->funcA(10);
  return;
}
```

For C++11 something like

```
template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value, void>::type
funcB(T* object) {
  object->funcA(10);
  return;
}
```

should do the job.
[Try it here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8eP96cdvulsuf08X).

Comment: does this also work with member functions?

Comment: @MQwadezo What error message do you get with MSVC?

Comment: the problem wasn't msvc, the problem is that in my real code, funcB is a member function

Comment: I see. It should not be an issue with `funcB` is a member function as well. What kind of error message do you get?

Comment: i don't know exactly how the error is in english, the error-code is ```LNK2019```.

Comment: Have you defined the function in a `cpp` file? `LNK2019` is typically connected to implementing a template function in a `cpp` file. For a template the declaration as well as the definition should go into the header.

Comment: i put the definition in the header and it works now! but why must the definition be in the header file?

Comment: It is like this with templates. A template is like a form that is filled out, the template type `T` is a placeholder: Whenever the compiler encounters an appropriate template argument it will insert it as the template parameter and create a new version of this function. In C++ each `.cpp` file is processed independently while the header files act like table of contents. So each `.cpp` file has to be able to fill out this form by its own. If you put the declaration into a `.cpp` another `.cpp` can't instantiate its required version of this function.

Comment: This means if you put it into a `.cpp` file it works as long as you either instantiate it inside the `.cpp` or you only use the template functions from that particular `.cpp`. I have written a comment about it some time ago with some links if you want to have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67127148/templates-coding-only-in-header-file/67170870#67170870