# Overload operators on different templated types with C++ concepts

Tags: c++, templates, linear-algebra, c++20, derived-class

I am trying to provide out-of-class definitions of arithmetic operators `+-*/` (and in-place `+=` etc.) for differently templated types. I read that C++20 concepts is the good way to go, as one could constrain the input/output type to provide only one templated definition, although I could not find much examples of this...

I am using a type-safe vector as base class:

```cpp
// vect.cpp
template<size_t n, typename T> 
struct Vect {
    
    Vect(function<T(size_t)> f) {
        for (size_t i=0; i < n; i++) {
            values[i] = f(i);
        }
    }
    
    T values [n];

    T operator[] (size_t i) {
        return values[i];
    }
}
```

I have a derived class for tensors like so:

```cpp
// tensor.cpp
template <typename shape, typename T>
struct Tensor : public Vect<shape::size, T> {
    // ... same initiliazer and [](size_t i)
}
```

and I shall also define a derived class for read-only views/slices, overriding `operator []` to jump accross strides. I'd like to hard code little more than `fmap` and `fold` methods inside each class and avoid reproducing boilerplate code as much as possible.

I first had a bit of trouble coming up with a suitable concept for `Vect<n,T>`-like classes due to different template parameters, but the one below seems to work:

```cpp
// main.cpp
template<typename V, int n, typename T> 
concept Vector = derived_from<V, Vect<n, T>>

template<int n, typename T, Vector<n, T> V>
V operator + (const V& lhs, const V& rhs) {
    return V([&] (int i) {return lhs[i] + rhs[i];});
}

int main () {
    size_t n = 10;
    typedef double T;
    Vect<n,T> u ([&] (size_t i) {return static_cast<T>(i) / static_cast<T>(n);});
    log("u + u", u);
    return 0;
}
```

`Error: template deduction/substitution failed, could not deduce template parameter 'n'`

**Try 2:**

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35853204/c-overloading-operator-in-a-template-class) I figure out-of-class definition has to be a little more verbose, so I added a couple lines to `vect.cpp`.

This seems contrived as it would require (3 * N_operators) type signature definitions, where avoiding code duplication is what motivates this question. Plus I don't really understand what the `friend` keyword is doing here.

```cpp
// vect.cpp
template<size_t n, typename T>
struct Vect;

template<size_t n, typename T> 
Vect<n, T> operator + (const Vect<n, T>& lhs, const Vect<n, T>& rhs);

template<size_t n, typename T>
struct Vect {
    ...
    friend Vect operator +<n, T> (const Vect<n, T>& lhs, const Vect<n, T>& rhs);
    ...
}
```

`Error: undefined reference to Vect<10, double> operator+(Vect<10, double> const&, Vect<10, double> const&)' ... ld returned 1 exit status`

I am guessing the compiler is complaining about implementation being defined in `main.cpp` instead of `vect.cpp`?

**Question:** What is the correct C++ way to do this? Are there any ways to make the compiler happy e.g. with header files?

I am really looking for DRY answers here, as I know the code would work with a fair amount of copy-paste :)

Thanks!

Comment: Regarding try 2: Templates are generally declared and defined in the header file else this might result in linker errors (more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67170870/9938686)).

Comment: Your lambda needs an explicit `static_cast<T>`. So either `[&] (size_t i) {return static_cast<T>(i) / static_cast<T>(n);}` or a templated lambda. Currently `u` is initialised with `0`.

Comment: You cannot override a non-virtual function.

Comment: @2b-t thanks for the pointer. Right for `static_cast<T>` writing `(T)i / (T)n` also works

Comment: @shevket `(T)` is less expressive than `static_cast<T>(...)`. `(T)` can mean very different things in different context: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-const-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used)

Comment: @2b-t edited again for good practice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template<int n, typename T, Vector<n, T> V>
V operator + (const V& lhs, const V& rhs) {
  return V([&] (int i) {return lhs[i] + rhs[i];});
}
```

here, you have to have a way to deduce `n` and `T`.  Your `V` does not provide that; C++ template argument deduction does not invert non-trivial template constructs (because doing so in general is Halt-hard, it instead has a rule that this makes it non-deduced).

Looking at the body, you don't *need* `n` or `T`.

```
template<Vector V>
V operator + (const V& lhs, const V& rhs) {
  return V([&] (int i) {return lhs[i] + rhs[i];});
}
```

this is the signature you want.

The next step is to make it work.

Now, your existing concept has issues:

```
template<typename V, int n, typename T> 
concept Vector = derived_from<V, Vect<n, T>>
```

this concept is looking at the **implementation** of `V` to see if it is derived from `Vect`.

Suppose someone rewrote `Vect` with `Vect2` with the same interface.  Shouldn't it also be a vector?

Looking at the implementation of Vect:

```
Vect(function<T(size_t)> f) {
    for (size_t i=0; i < n; i++) {
        values[i] = f(i);
    }
}

T values [n];

T operator[] (size_t i) {
    return values[i];
}
```

it can be constructed from a `std::function<T(size_t)>` and has a `[size_t]->T` operator.

```
template<class T, class Indexer=std::size_t>
using IndexResult = decltype( std::declval<T>()[std::declval<Indexer>()] );
```

this is a trait that says what the type result of `v[0]` is.

```
template<class V>
concept Vector = requires (V const& v, IndexResult<V const&>(*pf)(std::size_t)) {
  typename IndexResult<V const&>;
  { V( pf ) };
  { v.size() } -> std::convertible_to<std::size_t>;
};
```

there we go, a duck-type based concept for `Vector`.  I added a `.size()` method requirement.

We then write some operations on all `Vector`s:

```
template<Vector V>
V operator + (const V& lhs, const V& rhs) {
  return V([&] (int i) {return lhs[i] + rhs[i];});
}
template<Vector V>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, V const& v)
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
        os << v[i] << ',';
    return os;
}
```

fix up your base `Vect` a tad:

```
template<std::size_t n, typename T> 
struct Vect {
    Vect(std::function<T(std::size_t)> f) {
        for (std::size_t i=0; i < n; i++) {
            values[i] = f(i);
        }
    }
    
    T values [n];

    T operator[] (std::size_t i) const { // << here
        return values[i];
    }
    constexpr std::size_t size() const { return n; } // << and here
};
```

and then these tests pass:

```
constexpr std::size_t n = 10;
typedef double T;
MyNS::Vect<n,T> u ([&] (size_t i) {return (T)i / (T)n;});
std::cout << "u + u" << (u+u) << "\n";
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/n1Tdnbh9K).

(I used namespaces properly, because I feel icky when I don't).

Note that `operator+` is found via ADL because it is in `MyNS` as is `Vect`.  For types outside of `MyNS` you'd have to `using MyNS::operator+` it into current scope.  This is intentional and pretty much unavoidable.

(If you inherit from something in `MyNS` it will also be found).

...

TL;DR

Concepts should generally be *duck typed*, that is depend on what you can do with the type, not how the type is implemented.  The code does not appear to care if you inherit from a specific type or template, it just wants to use some methods; so test **that**.

This also avoids trying to deduce the template arguments to the `Vect` class; we instead extract it from the interface.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have to look into it deeper but I like the constructor signature requirement :)

Comment: @shevket Also consider `std::declval<IndexResult<V const&>(*)(std::size_t)>()` -- that could avoid a compiler warning about "no return paths produce a value" or whatever.

Comment: Could you provide a few hints about file splitting as well? Can I split `struct Vect {...}` and `template <Vector V> ...` in different .cpp or .hpp files?

Comment: I do get `error: no return statement in function returning non-void` with the `{ V([] (size_t) -> IndexResult<V const&>{}) }` underlined. Could you be more precise about where to put `declval<IndexResult<V const&>(*)(size_t)>()` and on the syntax of these constructs? Cheers!

Comment: Ok I updated the constructor requirement to `{ V (declval<...>()) }`. I put the concept and operator+ definition in a file "alg.h" and included it in a file "vect.h" defining the Vect class and it seems to work (not the otherway around, the concept should be imported from the instance). I don't know about best practices though...

Comment: @shevket What you describe seems reasonbale.

Comment: as said I like the constructor constraint but what you to put in it remains quite opaque! Could you edit your answer with a few details so that I mark it accepted? (e.g. why your 1st suggestion doesn't compile, and what does the star mean in `Target(*)(Source)` when `Target(Source)` compiles as well inside the declval?)

Comment: @shev it didnpt compile because you have sensible warnings and warnings as errors on.  The rest, function pointer, and decay of return values.

Comment: Ok well I tried to compile the former without -Wall etc and it gave me lots of linker errors and "relocation against read-only section" blah blah. The thread is diverging a bit so I'll ask more specific questions later though. Thanks for the help!