# C++/CLI typename Template As argument : Compilation error

Tags: templates, c++-cli

I just want to do a simple function which has typename as input arguments to convert managed array to

The `.h` file:

```
template <typename TYPE>
static void managed2unmanagedArray( interior_ptr<TYPE> ptrsrc, TYPE *ptrdest, UINT32 size );
```

The `.cpp` file:

```
template <typename TYPE>
void cUtil::managed2unmanagedArray( interior_ptr<TYPE> ptrsrc, TYPE *ptrdest, UINT32   size ) {
for ( UINT32 byte= 0; byte< size; byte++ ) {

    *ptrdest = *ptrsrc;
    ptrdest++;
    ptrsrc++;

}
```

}

Both .cpp and .h passed compilation
and when i test using the code:

```
array<UINT8>^ testUnitSrc = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
UINT8 testUnitDest[8] = {0};

cUtil::managed2unmanagedArray<UINT8>    (&testUnitSrc[0],&testUnitDest[0],sizeof(testUnitDest));
```

fails with the following error:

> error LNK2020: unresolved token (06000004) nsUtil.cUtil::managed2unmanagedArray

Comment: wheredo you define namespace nsUtils?

Comment: thanks for your reply, it is on the .h file.

namespace nsUtil {

ref class cUtil {

public:
 cUtil(void);
 static void managed2unmanagedByteArray( interior_ptr<UINT8> ptrsrc, UINT8 *ptrdest, UINT32 size ); 
 static void unmanaged2managedByteArray( UINT8 *ptrdest, interior_ptr<UINT8> ptrsrc, UINT32 size ); 
 
 template <typename TYPE>
 static void managed2unmanagedArray( interior_ptr<TYPE> ptrsrc, TYPE *ptrdest, UINT32 size ); 
};

}

Comment: I have other method written besides the template methods, they all work but not for the template related method, so i begin to suspect the way I wrote the code... thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you instatiate your template, the implementation of the template method needs to be available.

That is, in your test code, the implementation of managed2unmanagedArray needs to be included (its currently in your .cpp, and presumably you are not including it).

The typical solution to this is to put the implementation of your template into the header file.  There are other approaches you can use as well.

See [C++ template function compiles in header but not implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040480/c-template-function-compiles-in-header-but-not-implementation)