# C++ -- Function returning vector of template type

Tags: c++, templates, vector, compilation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

I am having trouble compiling a function that returns a vector of template type. The code compiles if I remove the template and replace with `double`. Also, this problem only occurs if the function definition and prototype are not in the same file. I compile using:

```
g++ func.cpp main.cpp
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <vector>
#include "func.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    double x_min = 0.0;
    double x_max = 1.0;
    int N = 20;
    std::vector<double> x = linspace(x_min,x_max,N);

    return 0;
}
```

func.cpp:

```
#include "func.h"

template <class T>
std::vector<T> linspace(T x1, T x2, int N)
{
    std::vector<T> x(N);
    if(N == 1)
    {
        x[0] = x2;
        return x;
    }

    T delta_x = (x2-x1)/(N-1);

    for(int ii = 0; ii < N; ii++)
    {
        x[ii] = x1 + ii*delta_x;
    }

    x[N-1] = x2;
    return x;
}
```

func.h:

```
#include <vector>

template <class T>
std::vector<T> linspace(T x1, T x2, int N);
```

The compiler produces the following output:

```
/tmp/cclptwq7.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x45): undefined reference to `std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > linspace<double>(double, double, int)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Template classes should not be split up into `.hpp` and `.cpp` files.

The member function implementations must be also be included in a compilation unit (for example, your `main.cpp`), otherwise the compiler has no way of knowing how to build the template class with the types you provide as template arguments. You *could* also `#include "func.cpp"` in `main.cpp`, but that would be ugly.

As David suggested, https://stackoverflow.com/a/3040706/713961 gives you more information if you're curious.

Comment: Technically incorrect. They *can*, as long as you do it properly, and accept the limitations it implies. Normally, people do not do it, because of all the tradeoffs involved, but it *can* be done. :)

Answer (score 0):

Templates must be defined in the same file or else you get a linker error. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3040706/701092) for more info.