# Define template in .cpp and retain "genericness"

Tags: c++, templates

**DISCLAIMER: Before you start marking this as a duplicate question please read it in whole. Thank you.**

I really dislike defining template functions/classes in headers. I would like to know if there is a more elegant solution.

Say I have a class, like so:

```
// A.h
template<typename T>
class A
{
    ...
};
```

I've stumbled upon multiple semi-solutions:

- Also include the definition source file in the client source file:

  `#include "A.h"

  #include "A.cpp"`
- Include the definition source in the class template header, but remove the cpp file from compilation
- Explicit template instantiation `template class A<int>;`

The first two solutions work, but they seem... well, ugly.

Of all of these solutions, the last seems the most elegant (to me at least) but this way I lose "genericness" of the template, because I have to instantiate it for each type.

Can anyone please tell me a way (if possible) to keep the definition separate from declaration while still retaining the genericness of the template class?

Comment: For option 2: When naming the file with an extension like tpp, txx your IDE/build system will not add it for compilation. This method is widely used.

Comment: This question *is* a duplicate.  What makes this question special?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ template function compiles in header but not implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040480/c-template-function-compiles-in-header-but-not-implementation)

Comment: @JohnDibling I did my research. I already found answers like the one you've posted in that thread (I even noted that in my question). What I was asking for here is a more elegant solution if one exists. A silver bullet if you will. On an unrelated note, it's quirks like this that make me realize why some people really dislike C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like first or second, I recommend like this:

```
// C.h
template <typename T> class C
{
    C();
}

#include "C_impl.h"

//C_impl.h
template <typename T> C<T>::C() { }
```

Unfortunately, there's no way to separate definition and declaration perfectly because compiler needs both to instant template

Comment: Thank you, though I might rename the extension to .iml or .ipp for better readability. I was kinda hoping for a silver bullet but since it's not possible I guess this will have to do.

Comment: @blashyrk I faced the same problem, and I used this solution because of editor highlighting and other support. you may need to edit your editor's setting.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong in defining the methods in the `.h` file, but I prefer to use the extension `.hpp` instead.

Another options you may consider are:

Declare the class on the top of the file, and defined the methods at the bottom.

```
// A.hpp
template<typename T>
class A {
    void someMethod();
    ...
};

template <class T> A<T>::someMethod() {
    // code
}
```

Put the implementation in a `.ipp` file, and include it at the end of the `.hpp` file:

```
// A.hpp
template<typename T>
class A {
    void someMethod();
    ...
};

#include "detail/A.ipp"


// detail/A.ipp   
template <class T> A<T>::someMethod() {
    // code
}
```

Explanation on `.ipp` files: http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2003/08/51197.php:

> If you want to split up your template sources into interface and 
>   implementation (there are lots of good reasons to do that, including 
>   controlling instantiation), you can't very well use the same name 
>   (foo.hpp) twice, and foo.cpp wouldn't be appropriate for either one. 
>   foo.ipp clearly delineates the file as an implementation file intended
>   to  be #included in foo.hpp.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me!

Answer (score 1):

I have seen in some headers that the template class definition will be in headers and the implementation will be included in a filename with extension ".inl" and again this "inl" file will be included at the end of header file.

This way your header will be clean and whoever includes this header file will automatically include the implementation through "inl" files, provided "inl" file is also distributed with header files.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me!